# Programatically forward Gmail messages & retain message formatting?

Tags: c#, gmail, html-email

Is there any way to programatically forward email messages from Gmail to another email address, and retain all formatting - using C#?

I've got an ASP.NET web application which needs to do this.  Currently, I'm download emails using IMAP, with the [ImapX](http://hellowebapps.com/products/imapx/) library, storing the HTML & text bodies, and then creating a new message with this data and sending the message using the System.Net.Mail class, but messages are losing their formatting, as well as any attached images, etc.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to just store the message-id in the database (which I'm doing already), and then be able to programatically connect to Gmail, retrieve the message using the specified message-id, and forward this to another email address.  Is there any easy way to do this?

Any thoughts or advice would be most appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Mail.dll from lesnikowski.

This how you would do it using the dll: http://www.lesnikowski.com/blog/index.php/how-to-forward-email

Comment: Thanks. Haven't been able to get this to work so far, but have contacted the developer.

Comment: yah, the developer is very good. He responded to my questions in about a day

Comment: The problem was with the port (SMTP over SSL uses 465: http://www.lesnikowski.com/blog/index.php/default-ports-for-email-protocols)

Comment: Marking this answer as accepted.  I didn't manage to get it forwarding email properly, but I think that was more due to something weird with Gmail rather than the component itself - messages were sent without error, but just never arrived. However, I ended up using this anyway for downloading email as it handles HTML emails much better than the free ImapX component.  Developer support was also excellent with prompt, helpful replies to emails.